# Mysql Buscar registros con 3 datos y el min de un campo dentro de un rango de fechas

Tags: mysql

Buen día apreciados expertos y gurús,
tengo una duda con un Query de Mysql

Mi tabla actual se carga con 3 datos:
Nombre (varchar)- fecha (varchar) - hora (varchar)
Aparecen de esta manera los datos:

```
Juan - 18/05/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 18/06/2024 - 08:12:30
carlos- 17/06/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 19/06/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 20/06/2024 - 08:12:30
```

El tema que estoy teniendo es que, al correr la búsqueda que escribí, me encuentro que me trae los resultados pero no solo entre 2 fechas;
reconoce como dato el día pero me trae el mismo dia en meses anteriores que no están dentro del rango.
mi consulta que hago es:

```sql
SELECT Nombre, fecha, Min(hora) 
from rh_checador_en_uso 
where Nombre = "Juan" 
AND fecha between '18/06/2024' And '19/06/2024' 
group by Nombre, fecha
```

Por cierto, como dato adicional, al hacer la búsqueda debe mostrar solamente el registro con la hora  mínima del día, ya que en un mismo día pueden haber varios registros con diferentes horas.

Así se deberia ver:

```
Juan - 18/06/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 19/06/2024 - 08:12:30
```

Esto es lo que se ve realmente con mi busqueda

```
Juan - 18/05/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 18/06/2024 - 08:12:30
Juan - 19/06/2024 - 08:12:30
```

Espero darme a entender
y muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: si fecha es varchar, entonces no es una fecha, y un between entre cadenas es algo impredecible... de ahi en adelante, todo esta mal... asi que corrige eso y todo se va a arrelgar...

Comment: Las fechas en la BD, si son VARCHAR, van en formato `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`. De esa forma los ordenamientos y búsquedas se hacen de forma natural. Si usas dd/mm/YYYY como tu caso, te va a devolver cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se da porque la fecha está almacenada como cadena de caracteres varchar. En este tipo de dato, la regla para comparar es según el código correspondiente a cada caracter que aparece en la cadena. Las reglas para comparar fechas son muy diferentes.

La mejor solución a tu problema es almacenar las fechas como fechas, utilizando el tipo de dato `date` y las horas como horas, utilizando el tipo de dato `time`.

Si no está en tus manos cambiar la estructura, entonces la siguiente sería almacenar las fechas en un *formato* donde lo que tiene más peso aparezca al inicio de la cadena, lo que hará más natural las comparaciones y ordenamientos, por ejemplo en formato 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Finalmente, si esto no es posible, entonces puedes escribir la consulta convirtiendo las cadenas a fechas para hacer las comparaciones. OJO que esto **NO lo recomiendo**; en primer lugar, porque hará que la consulta sea menos eficiente y porque vas a toparte con otra serie de *problemas* que vas a tener que ir resolviendo para realizar ordenamientos y otras comparaciones a todo lo largo del desarrollo de un sistema.

Para convertir de cadena a fecha, utiliza la función [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). La consulta podría quedar algo como:

```sql
select Nombre, fecha, Min(hora) 
  from rh_checador_en_uso 
 where Nombre = "Juan" 
   AND str_to_date(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') between '18/06/2024' and '19/06/2024' 
 group by Nombre, fecha
```